# Jasmin in CLASSPATH

Tags: java, classpath, jasmin

I have download jasmin.jar from http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=100746

I have changed my CLASSPATH to the following:

```
echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Sun\SDK\lib;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\lib\jasmin\jasmin.jar;
```

The following command works without a problem:

```
java -jar C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\lib\jasmin\jasmin.jar -g Greeter.j
```

But the following does not works:

```
java Jasmin -g Greeter.j
```

I am wondering as to what am I doing wrong and how to fix it, so I can easily run the Jasmin from the command line and convert jasmin code to .class.

I did not find any useful information at: http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/guide.html
Which says the following:

> The jasmin.jar file is an executable
>   JAR file that runs Jasmin. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> java -jar jasmin.jar myfile.j
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> java Jasmin myfile.j
> ```
>
> (if jasmin.jar is already in your
>   classpath)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if perhaps the main class has been changed since that document was written, but I just looked up what the actual main class is.

If you check the manifest of the jar file, you can see that the main class is actually jasmin.Main

If you have the jar file in your CLASSPATH, you should be able to just do the following:

java jasmin.Main -g Greeter.j

Answer (score 0):

It turns out jasmin.jar is NOT in your classpath.

the -jar option tell the interpreter to execute the Main class that is in the specified jar file ( which it is Jasmin )

In the second, you're telling, execute the class called "Jasmin" with this args, but the intepreter ( java.exe ) does not know where that file is.

You could do the following:

1) Set jasmin.jar in your classpath in windows in environment variable CLASSPATH ( you mentiond that is already there, but didn't mention HOW did you put it )  probably is was through a command prompt windows and tried to use it in other?

2) Specify the classpath from the command line

```
 java -classpath C:\a\b\c\jasmin.jar Jasmin -g Greejer.j
```

That should work.

Sometimes I have had problems with the empty spaces in the classpath for instance

C:\Progrma Files....;C:\My\Jar.jar

And didn't work. How are you setting your CLASSPATH env var?

Comment: I setted the classpath by clicking on the "Environment Variable" button in System. Then I manually edited the variable. I added the jasmin.jar location at the end of VALUE of CLASSPATH.

Comment: Mh strange, have you tried the 2nd option I mention? Using -classpath modifier?

Answer (score 0):

Change your classpath from

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Sun\SDK\lib;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\lib\jasmin\jasmin.jar;
```

to

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip";C:\Sun\SDK\lib;C:\Sun\SDK\jdk\lib\jasmin\jasmin.jar;
```

Essentially, put quotes around any paths which have spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

just call `jasmin.jar yourFile.j`